# How to format existing data into columns on csv file in python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file with data in each row separated with space. I want to format these datas in columns. So if I have 5 values separated by space in a row then I want to create 5 columns. My csv file looks like following,
[image]

I want to format them on 7 columns. I'm using pandas and trying to set the column like this

```
dataFrame.columns= ['Frame',  'xmin', 'xmax', 'ymin','ymax', 'occluded', 'Label']
```

But its showing me an error

> ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values
>   have 7 elements

Comment: For future reference, pleace don't post screenshots of data, especially if you have text files (csv), which can easily be pasted here. Otherwise you kinda expect us to manually retype your data from the screenshot to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use separator `\s+` (whitespace) or parameter `delim_whitespace` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
names = ['Frame',  'xmin', 'xmax', 'ymin','ymax', 'occluded', 'Label']
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep='\s+', names=names)

names = ['Frame',  'xmin', 'xmax', 'ymin','ymax', 'occluded', 'Label']
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', delim_whitespace=True, names=names)
```

Error means all values are in one column, so cannot be assigned 7 column names.